# Get callback from closures inside loop

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, closures

I am using a recursive function which calls children function which in-return call this function on certain conditions. These functions use a closure to return the data as they are required to some processing which includes an API call. Since, I am using a closure to return data recursively, my functions take rawData as parameter. This raw data gets overriden when I call this function in a for-loop.

I cannot avoid using a closure for the function because of the API call, hence, need a solution in which I can achieve a similar structure with/without using dispatch group.

Example of the above structure using dispatch Group ->

```
func recursive(rawDataMap: [String: [rawData]], completion: @escaping ([String: [ProcessedData]]) -> Void) {
    var processedDataMap = [String: [ProcessedData]]()
    let parentDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

// have not handled storing the key for the example structure but the key will be maintained in the actual code.

    for (key,data) in rawDataMap {
        parentDispatchGroup.enter()
        if data.count > 1 {
            let childDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
            var processedDataArray = [processedData]()
            for item in data {
                childDispatchGroup.enter()
                children(rawData: item){ processedData in
                    processedDataArray.append(processedData)
                    childDispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }
            childDispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main){
                processedDataMap[key] = processedDataArray
                parentDispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
    parentDispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(processedDataMap)
    }
}

func children(rawData: rawData, completion: @escaping (ProcessedData) -> Void) {
    //condition to check if recursive call required or not
    if rawData.nested {
        recursive(rawDataMap: rawData.rawDataMap){ processedDataMap in
            completion(ProcessedData(nested: true, processedDataMap: processedDataMap))
        }
    } else {
        processing(rawData: rawData){ processedData in
            completion(processedData)
        }
    }
}

func processing(rawData: rawData, completion: @escaping (ProcessedData) -> Void) {
    
    //function to get API params from rawData
    let params = getParamsFromData(rawData: rawData)
    networkClient.API(params: Params){ processedData in
        completion(processedData)
    }
}
```